# I don't understand Autowired in Spring

Tags: java, spring, javabeans, autowired

**ApplicationContext**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<context:annotation-config />

    <bean id="beanFactory" class="testSpring.BeanFactory" />

    <bean id="a1" class="testSpring.A">
        <property name="name" value="I am A one!"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="a2" class="testSpring.A">
        <property name="name" value="I am A two!"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="b" class="testSpring.B">
        <property name="name" value="I am B!"></property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

**Main**

```
public class Main 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        System.out.println("Avvio applicazione: Main invocato");
        AbstractApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
                "ApplicationContext.xml");

        BeanFactory ai = applicationContext.getBean("beanFactory", BeanFactory.class);


    }
}
```

**A** *(The same for B bean)*

```
public class A {

    private String name;

    public A(){

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("restriction")
    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        System.out.println("Bean A created, name: " + name);
    }

    public String getName(){
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }   

}
```

**BeanFactory**

```
public class BeanFactory {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier(value="a1")
    private A a;

    public void setA(A a){
        this.a = a;
    }

    public void printAName(){
        System.out.println("Classe AInstantiator: AInstantiator.printAName -> a.getName() = " + a.getName());
    }

}
```

This is the result of running:

```
Avvio applicazione: Main invocato
Bean A created, name: I am A one!
Bean A created, nome: I am A two!
Bean B created, name: I am B!
```

How it's possible?!

1) Why *A two* is created? I specified in the @Qualifier a1 bean, not both! Qualifier annotation isn't used to binding a specific bean of the same class? Right?

2) Why Bean B is created? I don't binding it with @Autowired.

If I remove

```
 @Autowired 
 @Qualifier(value="a1")
```

from BeanFactory, the result is the same! It's not possible.. I don't understand. Maybe the compiler is crashed? Help, please!

Comment: Sounds like you want [Lazy-initialized beans](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-lazy-init).

Comment: @BeauGrantham is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The beans are eagerly initialized by default which means the container ["eagerly create and configure all singleton beans as part of the initialization process"](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-lazy-init). Simply, the @PostConstruct methods are called on start up regardless of any autowiring or other dependency injection.

If you want otherwise, you need to set :

```
lazy-init="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

Beans are eagerly created by default. If you'd like to delay this you can use [lazy-initialization](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-lazy-init).